# Azure app sharing

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I have a azure app. Is it possible to share it as free aplication(so anyone will be able to deploy it on own azure account) without giving out source code and recompiling it each time. I'm using azure database, so I need connection string to it for making requests and now it string is hardcoded. Also I'm using hardcoded connection string to access to blobs and dynamic instances allocation. Is there the way to take these strings out and allow to change it wihout recompiling project?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. When you compile a cloud project, it creates a package file and a configuration file. If you want, you could distribute those files.

Regarding removing connection strings and other settings, one thing you could do is create a separate cloud project that has the same settings as your main cloud project. Only thing is that the settings which are specific to a user environment (like connection strings) would be empty. Then you would package this cloud project and distribute `cspkg` and `cscfg` file.

To elaborate further, take a look at the screenshot below:

[image]

Essentially here I have 2 cloud projects (`Web.Azure` and `Web.Test.Local`) and both of the cloud projects are referencing same `Web` project. Now in our case `Web.Azure` is our development cloud project and `Web.Test.Local` is the test cloud projects. Both of these projects have same settings name e.g. `SqlConnectionString`. Now in the `Web.Azure`, I have specified its value to be that of our development SQL Server but in `Web.Test.Local` I can specify any other value. When we want our testers to test the application, they get the package for `Web.Test.Local` and they get the settings based on that project. Taking the same analogy, you could have two cloud projects (let's call then `Dev` and `Release`). What you have to do is use the same settings in both cloud projects but there won't be any values for those settings in your `Release` project.

Yet another approach you could take is what's described in this blog post: http://blog.paraleap.com/post/2011/09/13/Managing-environments-in-a-distributed-Azure-or-other-cloud-based-NET-solution.

Please note that `cspkg` file is essentially a `zip` file. I could change the extension of the package file from cspkg to zip and unzip that file and see all the binaries. I could then use a tool like RedGate's Reflector or Telerik's Just Decomplie to decompile the binary files and possibly look at the source code. To avoid that, you may want to obfuscate the binaries before packaging them.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately I don't understand everything clear yet. I need to use connection strings(changed by end user) in my code. How can I get it there?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to give a compiled package with empty connection string settings so that when a user downloads the package, they can specify these settings based on their environment and then deploy this package in their cloud service. Am I correct?

Comment: Probably I can retrieve it from .cscfg file in execution time?

Comment: Updated my answer. HTH.